# Android topoche searchable spinner cannot cast error

Tags: java, android, android-spinner

[image: Error Message]
Inconvertible types; cannot cast 'android.view.View' to 'com.toptoche.searchablespinnerlibrary.SearchableSpinner'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spinner 1 is assigned to the wrong thing you have it assigned as a View not a spinner
Easier way to do this,

Before your `onCreate` you do

```
Spinner spinnername;
```

so then the spinner is available to call throughout the entire activity

Then under your your `onCreate` you do

```
spinnername=findViewById(R.id.nameofspinnerinxml);
```

And in your xml you must make your spinner something like this

```
  <com.toptoche.searchablespinnerlibrary.SearchableSpinner
    android:id="@+id/nameofspinnerinxml"
    style="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.Spinner"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="51dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="24dp" />
```

Adding a more complete example for you

```
Spinner spinner1;

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_edit_project);

        spinner1=findViewById(R.id.spinnerid);
```

and then in the xml

```
  <com.toptoche.searchablespinnerlibrary.SearchableSpinner
    android:id="@+id/spinnerid"
    style="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.Spinner"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="51dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="24dp" />
```

Comment: Why I am getting `Cannot resolve class com.toptoche.searchablespinnerlibrary.SearchableSpinner `

Comment: I have `AdroidX`

Comment: @Moeez , it is an external Library, You need to add it to your dependencies in Gradle
|compile 'com.toptoche.searchablespinner:searchablespinnerlibrary:1.3.1'